# Google Nearby Connections 2.0 capabilities

Tags: android, google-nearby

I am evaluating Google Nearby connections2.0 more specifically evaluating the synergy effect of it. For this I am evaluating it against Wifi, Bluetooth and BLE in totally offline scenario, without any router.

**Scenario**

One device is advertising, all others (8 devices in total) are discovering. On successful connection, I am sending simple Files of 20B, 200B and 33KB sizes for 30 secs straight to each connected device.

I am using android Samsung S6 [SM-G920F](https://www.sammobile.com/devices/galaxy-s6/specs/SM-G920F/) devices with android  version: 6.0.1 and playservices version 12.8.74

I have following issues/questions

**Q1**:  First of all at max 3 to 4 devices could be connected simulatenously more than this  results into disconnect event of other devices. Even if only 3 devices are connected, and I am continuously sending message for 30seconds, one of them disconnected ? In simpler words, cannot sustain connectivity with any device for more than 45 secs. usually disconnection occur between 25 - 45 secs

**Q2**:  I cannot send message/file continuously for 30 seconds like we can do with the Wifi like this

```
While(30sec){
   bluetoothSocket.outputStream.write(bytes)
}
```

Because if I try to do this then I got the exception of too much work.I have to wait for the the callback in `onTransferPayLoadUpdate()`

**Q3**:  If I try to send the file of 1MB or more to other peers, peer received the file successfully in `onPayloadReceived` callback  but server/sender receive the successful status after too much delay. In my case it's between 1 mins to 5 mins after client callback. And I cannot send new file until I got the success callback on server. If I try to send it before getting the callback, nothing happens. Literally nothing. So In essence I can only send file of 1MB once then I have to resent both the devices to send another file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be broken up into 3 separate questions. It helps future developers search easier. So if you get the time to do that, let me know and I'll split up my answer as well. But anyway, let's get into it!

A1: Nearby Connections has 3 separate strategies. The more limited the strategy, the more types of mediums we can use. So with that in mind, and with no router involved, P2P_CLUSTER will only use Bluetooth. It's the most general strategy, so it has the fewest mediums available.

All Android devices use mobile Bluetooth chips, which are unfortunately weak (but small and power sensitive), and that causes them to have a theoretical 7 device limit but a practical 3~4 device limit. To make things worst, that limit is eaten up by smart watches and paired headphones as well. That's why you're running into problems.

P2P_STAR and P2P_POINT_TO_POINT are both much more limited, because you can't connect in any direction. You need to choose who the host is beforehand and have everyone scan for and connect to that host. But you get the added benefit of WiFi hotspots, which have higher bandwidth and a larger number of simultaneous devices supported. I've seen 7 devices happily connected to a Lollipop device.

If you want to go beyond that, into the 10s and 100s, and a router isn't available, you'll have to build a mesh network. I can link you to examples of how to do that if you're interested. We don't offer support for that within Connections, but others have built meshes on top of us so we can point you in the right direction.

A2: Can you include a stack trace of the error you're seeing? Payload.Type.STREAM was built for continuously sending data. The other payload types should also work too, baring some rare but potential issues like BYTE payloads filling up the phones RAM.

A3: Both devices need to wait for onPayloadTransferUpdate(SUCCESS). onPayloadReceived is only a header, and means that there's an incoming file or stream but that the data hasn't been received yet. For byte payloads, we actually send the full byte payload inside the header so that's the only time data is immediately available.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I will post these questions separately over the weekend with your answers.

Comment: Ahhh I had totally the different understanding, I thought nearby switched between wifi and Bluetooth to have more range and more active connections.

Comment: We do switch between WiFi and Bluetooth, to get the highest bandwidth possible. If we initially connect over a low bandwidth medium, like Bluetooth, we have a small protocol that shares all the mediums both devices support so that we can upgrade to the best medium. However, some mediums, like WiFi Hotspots, have some very heavy limitations. You can only host or connect to a WiFi Hotspot -- you can't do both at the same time. So that's why it's only available on P2P_STAR and POINT_TO_POINT.

Comment: @Xlythe I would like to build a mesh network that connects and shares data to multiple connecting devices. 10s to 100s. For example in a classroom setup and wifi router isn't available. Could you point me in the right direction? I have also asked a question on Nearby @ https://stackoverflow.com/q/52773197/7809801

Comment: @Xlythe, is there any limitation in discovering a near by device if disconnects frequently?    We are trying to build a mesh network which need to be running in complete offline mode on android more reliably. Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you scan before reconnecting, it should be fine.