# Maximum number of device which can be connected on Google's nearby connection API

Tags: android, api, google-nearby

What is the maximum number of devices that can be connected using Google's nearby connection API?

Answer (score 2):

I can't post this as a comment but:
this question might have what you want
[Google Nearby Connections 2.0 capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976470/google-nearby-connections-2-0-capabilities/51997757#51997757)

For those who can't open it:

> All Android devices use mobile Bluetooth chips, which are unfortunately weak (but small and power sensitive), and that causes them to have a theoretical 7 device limit but a practical 3~4 device limit.
>
> P2P_STAR and P2P_POINT_TO_POINT [...] WiFi hotspots, which have higher bandwidth and a larger number of simultaneous devices supported. I've seen 7 devices happily connected to a Lollipop device.
>
> If you want to go beyond that, into the 10s and 100s, and a router isn't available, you'll have to build a mesh network.